# Linux Shell Script = grep -o -P 'FE=.*? ' not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am still confuse that what i am doing wrong as i automate the git push pull and write a post receive, the below mentioned line store  commit log from developer end in a file but what it does wrong is it only store `FE=` .I want it to store `FE='anything that developer write here'`.

```
var_custom_FE_log="$( git log -1 --no-merges $branch | grep -o -P 'FE=.*? ' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `FE=value` you should removing the `-o` flag in grep. Compare:

```
$grep -o -P 'FE=.*?' <<< "FE=some text here"
FE=

$grep -P 'FE=.*?' <<< "FE=some text here"
FE=some text here
```

If there is only one declaration per line then there is no need to use lazy quantifier `.*?`. You could use `.*` and drop the `-P` flag:

```
$grep 'FE=.*' <<< "FE=some text here"
FE=some text here
```

Comment: I have tried it without -P as well but it only shows FE=

Comment: Could please add some output lines of `git log -1 --no-merges $branch`? In that way I can modify the regex accordingly.

Comment: Found my silly mistake, now it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything inherently wrong in your code. grep will return a string `FE=`, followed by (optionally) non-blank characters, and then a space. For example, if there would be a space immediately after the `FE=`, such as in

```
xxxx FE= anything that developer write here
```

you would get just *FE=*  (with trailing space), while the line

```
xxxx FE=anything that developer write here
```

would give you *FE=anything*  (again with trailing space).

BTW, while your -P flag is not wrong, -E would be sufficient in your case.

Comment: -E seems new to me, let me try this

Comment: -E is *extended regexp*, -P is *Perl regexp*. As I said, this should not matter in your concrete case, but for compatibility with other greps, -E is preferable if you have the choice.